# Host Header Web Application 404

Tags: host-header

When I create a site collection using this I always get 404 error,

```
New-SPSite 'http://portal.consto.com' -HostHeaderWebApplication 'http://myserver' -Name "Portal" -Language 1033 -Template 'APP#0' -OwnerAlias 'domain\username'
```

But when I create it without `HostHeaderWebApplication` it works fine :(.

Comment: Have you configured the new domain in DNS?

Comment: no but I added a host record in hosts file, which is '127.0.0.1 portal.consto.com'

Comment: @RobertLindgren , I edited my question i was creating site collection not webapplication sorry for mixing it up

Answer (score 0):

I faced a similar issue. I was experiencing this problem after deleting a host name based site collection and then recreating it (I was testing out some site creation scripts). I had a host entry for my web application that AutoSPInstaller created. I commented that out since I am using DNS entries. I was still getting a 404 error. I then did an iisreset and the site came up as expected.